# Is there a way to fill a LATEX template from a txt file?

Tags: templates, latex

I wonder if there is a way to do a LATEX template with different section, tables, enums, etc. and fill all of that with a corresponding txt or json file, so that I can compile different pdf with just changing the input file.
I know there is the textinput command but I would like to have one file for different input fields.

Like so:

```
%foo.tex
\section{\secOne}
    \textOne
\section{\secTwo}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \it21
    \item \it21
\end{enumerate}
```

```
#foo.txt
secOne:
    first section
secTwo:
    second section
textOne:
    this is a test
it21:
    foo
it21:
    bar
```

What are options here?
Is it common to use a .tex file to achive this?
Or can I also just use a formated txt file and seperate lines to fill out the template?

Comment: Sounds like an xy-problem. Maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/texplate is worth a look

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong you are planning on making a `compiler` that will translate your text document to `latex` format `tex` file. You can make your own `compiler` using `python`. I was working on a similar project but not with `latex` but with `power point` it is more of a `populator`. If you want to have a glance here is the repo https://github.com/altair00/XL-PPTX

I don't know if this will help you but this will give you an idea how to do what you are planning on doing.